# AJAX login to API via jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to set up a login form with AJAX/jQuery for an API.

In the terminal, when I run:
$ curl -d 'email=me@gmail.com&password=123123' https://api.xyzcompany.com/users/login.json

it returns a hash of an API token and Auth ID:
{"auth_token":"23049asfd0990235","auth_id":"2304990"}

Here's what I have so far:

```
    <form id="loginForm" action="login_submit" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <fieldset>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value=""  />
            </div>

            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value=""  />
            </div>

            <button type="submit" data-theme="g" name="submit" >Login</button>

        </fieldset>
    </form>

</div><!-- /page -->
```

```
$("#loginForm").submit(function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://api.xyzcompany.com/users/login.json",
        data:({
            email : $('#email').val(),
            password: $('#password').val()
        }),
        success: function(result)
        {
            if(result=='ok')
            {
                window.location = 'http://www.google.com/'; //just to show that it went through
            }
            else
            {
                $('#result').empty().addClass('error')
                    .append('Something is wrong.');
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

As you probably guessed, when I click submit, nothing happens. I'd really appreciate any help turning "curl -d" command into a working AJAX call. Thank you!

Comment: if you do a console.log(result); as the first function in success, are you getting any results or nothing at all?

Comment: I'm actually getting forwarded to a standard "site not found" error without or without it.

Comment: add datatype as json , `dataType: 'json', under type, url, data, or success

Comment: Still nothing getting "site not found"..

Comment: `window.location.href ` mate...

Comment: actually i think it's to do with their SSL that isn't working or responding properly so have u tested on curl ? and it works ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#loginForm").submit(function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        datatype:"json",
        url: "https://api.xyzcompany.com/users/login.json",
        data:({
            email : $('#email').val(),
            password: $('#password').val()
        }),
        success: function(result)
        {
            if(result && result.auth_token.length>1) // you should do your checking here
            {
                window.location = 'http://www.google.com/'; //just to show that it went through
            }
            else
            {
                $('#result').empty().addClass('error')
                    .append('Something is wrong.');
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: typo, dataType**** not datatype,